# How to correct the remote branch that my local branch is tracking?

Tags: git

I have local branches 'master' and vam-master' which tracks remote branch 'application/master' and 'application/vam-master' respectively.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  vam-master
  remotes/application/master
  remotes/application/pvm-master

 $ git branch -r
  m/ds-2.3.1_r1 -> application/master
  application/master
  application/vam-master
```

But for some reason now the 'vam-master' is tracking 'application/master', instead of 'application/vam-master'. How can I fix it?
When i do 'git status', I get:

```
$  git checkout vam-master
Switched to branch 'vam-master'
Your branch and 'application/master' have diverged,
and have 49 and 13 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch --set-upstream vam-master application/vam-master
git branch --set-upstream master application/master
```

Should do the trick. See also the man pages of [`git branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

Another option (less elegant) is to edit `.git/config` and correct the entries there.